# Error creating bean, Injection of autowired dependencies failed, Could not autowire field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext, spring-mybatis

Stuck with an exception and below is the log:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'speaker': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public final void org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.setSqlSessionTemplate(org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getNestedParameterType()Ljava/lang/Class

java web service:

```
@WebService
public class voiceRecognition extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
    @Autowired
    private Speaker speaker;


    @WebMethod
    public void test() {

        String userid = "111";
        String enrollmentid = "111";

        try{
        String test1 = speaker.getEnrollmentId(userid);  
        System.out.println(test1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

Speaker.java:

```
package ph.com.aub.mapper;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface Speaker {

    public String getEnrollmentId(@Param("userid") String userid);

}
```

Speaker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace = "ph.com.aub.mapper.Speaker">

<select id = "getEnrollmentId" resultType = "string" parameterType = "string">
Select enrollmentid from speakerids where userid = #{userid}
</select>

</mapper>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>voiceRecognitionPort</servlet-name>
     <!--<servlet-class>ph.com.aub.domain.voiceRecognition</servlet-class>-->
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>voiceRecognitionPort</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/voiceRecognitionPort</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ph.com.aub.domain.voiceRecognition"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ph.com.aub.mapper"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>


    <bean id="dataSourceSpeaker" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="Speakerdata"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactorySpeaker" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSpeaker"/>
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="ph.com.aub.domain"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mapperSpeaker" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="ph.com.aub.mapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactorySpeaker" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you configure the `basePackage` in `MapperScannerConfigurer` incorrectly. It should be package that containing the mapper class rather than the mapper class itself. So try to change the `basePackage` to:

```
<bean id="mapperSpeaker" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="ph.com.aub.mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactorySpeaker" />
</bean>
```

Comment: updated it, error now is: Error creating bean with name 'speaker': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public final void org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.setSqlSessionTemplate(org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getNestedParameterType()Ljava/lang/Class;

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError ` is most probably due to you use some incorrect version of JARs , which is another question and you need to revise your `pom.xml`

Comment: So if you think the problem in this questions is already solved by my suggestion , please consider to accept it or vote it up :P. It will also increase your reputation. Also , I usually don't want to answer if someone never accept the answer of their questions even that answer really solve their problem....

Comment: is there pom.xml when im using jdeveloper?

Comment: It depends on how you manage your JARS. If you use Maven (most popular way), it should have `pom.xml` . Open a new question with `pom.xml` and exception log ...